# Java JList unwanted toString() conversion

Tags: java, string, swing, drag-and-drop, jlist

My JList that I extended to let the user drag-and-drop reorder it (used [Reorder a JList with Drag-and-Drop](http://codeidol.com/java/swing/Lists-and-Combos/Reorder-a-JList-with-Drag-and-Drop/) and [Use drag and drop to reorder a list](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/Usedraganddroptoreorderalist.htm)) but it gives me a weird outcome. Instead of giving me my custom `JComponent`, it gives me the `.toString()` value of it. I set the model of my custom `JList` to `DefaultListModel<JComponent>` thinking it would work but it didn't.

Comment: those articles are severely outdated - the current way of customizing dnd is a custom TransferHandler, see the corresponding chapter in http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html

Comment: just noticed: you _never_ (as 99.99%) have items of type JComponent in the list.

Comment: To clarify @kleopatra 's comment. You do not have `JComponent` instances in your `ListModel`. But it is perfectly acceptable to let the renderer create custom `JComponent`s to represent your model items

Comment: @kleopatra I tried to change the articles to my need such as changing the model to `DefaultListModel<_JComponent_>` and adding real JComponents.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to create a custom `CellRenderer` for the object you want to render. By default, JList will show the toString value of the component (because DefaultListCellRenderer extends JLabel).

```
class MyRenderer extends DefaultListCellRenderer {
   public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList list, Object value, int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {
      Component c = super.getListCellRendererComponent(...);
      setText(getValue(value)); // where getValue is some method you implement that gets the text you want to render for the component
      return c;
}
```

If you don't actually want to render a string, create an implementation of CellRenderer that returns the component you want to render.

Comment: So I guess I implement `CellRenderer` while extending my JComponent and make getListCellRendererComponent() return my JComponent? I'll try it. Thanks:).